# looking left and right

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class mouselook : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float mouseSens = 100f;
    public Transform playerBody;
    float xr_1 =0f;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float y = 2 * Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * mouseSens * Time.deltaTime;
        float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * mouseSens * Time.deltaTime;
        xr_1 -= y;
        xr_1 = Mathf.Clamp(xr_1, -90f, 63f);
        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xr_1, 0f, 0f); 
        playerBody.Rotate(Vector3.up * mouseX);
    }
}
```

I wrote this code from a youtube video but with this code I cant turn my head left or right otherwise I can look sky or ground

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you rotating around X axis. You need to rotate around Y axis.

Unity uses a left-handed, Y-Up coordinate system. So to determine around what axis you need to rotate you can use your left had. Point big finger up will be a Y, point to straight is Z, and middle at 90 degree angle to your palm is X.

Your `Update` method should look like that:

```
 void Update()
    {
        float y = 2 * Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * mouseSens * Time.deltaTime;
        float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * mouseSens * Time.deltaTime;
        xr_1 -= y;
        xr_1 = Mathf.Clamp(xr_1, -90f, 63f);
        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xr_1, mouseX, 0f); 
    }
```